# How can I debug my React VR code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-360

I am using Visual Studio Code to build a React VR app and I am trying to figure out how I can inspect my code, i.e. through chrome dev tools. I have the React Developer Tools Chrome plugin installed however it is not detecting my React VR code. Are there any other ways?

I noticed nuclide, but that is only built for Atom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). A great and easy way to debug react-native apps. Since React-VR includes React Native as a dependency it also works with react-vr. (I used it with react-vr!).

Comment: I've installed, but I am having trouble finding out how to open it?

Comment: @ColinSygiel If you're using a mac, there should be "React Native Debugger" in your application folder.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but it is infinitely "waiting for client connection". I am listening on the same port, how can I connect?

Comment: The React Native Debugger should be opened before you build. But even after you built initially it should automatically detect your app, when you restart in the debug menu..